# Tasty Hunit testing of a parsec parser?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, parsec

I need to set up a test suit that lets me determine whether changes I make in a parsec parser does not break anything else down the line.

I am using `tasty` unit tests for this, and this is what I have:

```
simpleLabels :: TestTree
simpleLabels = testGroup "Simple label searches"
    [ testCase "List comparison (same length)" $ -- just a test to make sure that the @?= works like it should
      [1, 2, 3] `compare` [1,2,2] @?= LT
      , 
      testCase "Phonetic = a " $ 
        parse umeQuery "Source" "Phonetic = a " @?= Right ( LabelInLabelType "Phonetic" ["a"] "=")  
    ]
```

Now, this stream is parsed correctly by the parser when I run it in the REPL:

```
> parse umeQuery "something"  (pack  "Phonetic = a ")
Right (LabelInLabelType "Phonetic" ["a"] "=")
```

This is like it should be, and therefore what I set up in the test above.

Now, the test suite does not build at all, giving the error:

```
TestQueryParser.hs:29:55:
    No instance for (Eq ParseError) arising from a use of ‘@?=’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘parse umeQuery "Ume Query : " "Phonetic = a "
       @?= Right (LabelInLabelType "Phonetic" ["a"] "=")’
    In the expression:
      testCase "Phonetic = a "
      $ parse umeQuery "Ume Query : " "Phonetic = a "
        @?= Right (LabelInLabelType "Phonetic" ["a"] "=")
    In the second argument of ‘testGroup’, namely
      ‘[testCase "List comparison (same length)"
        $ [1, 2, ....] `compare` [1, 2, ....] @?= LT,
        testCase "Phonetic = a "
        $ parse umeQuery "Ume Query : " "Phonetic = a "
          @?= Right (LabelInLabelType "Phonetic" ["a"] "=")]’
```

How come I need this, considering the fact that a success/correct parsing should result in a `Right a` value?

What would be the best way to set up unit test for a parsec parser?

Comment: To compare an `Either e a` value both `e` and `a` should be instances of `Eq` as per definition of `Eq` for `Either`: `instance (Eq e, Eq a) => Eq (Either e a) where ...`, because there is no way for compler to know that you will have only `Right`s if type is `Either`. Parsec is not designed to check its error messages at all, as you can see. If you want to work with error messages, use [Megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec) (disclaimer: I'm its author). There is also [`hspec-megaparsec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-megaparsec) for what it's worth.

Comment: Instead of comparing `parse ... @?= Right ...`, you should first check the result of the parse is not `Left`, then compare the values directly (without first wrapping in `Right`). A simple way to do this in this case is `either (const $ assertFailure "...") (@?= (LabelInLabelType ...)) (parse ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for all helpful comments.

Indeed, like it was pointed out by @user2407038, better handling of the error message was required.

```
simpleLabels :: TestTree
simpleLabels = testGroup "Simple label searches"
    [
    testCase "Equality matching simple label" $ let 
        res = case (parse umeQuery "Source" "Phonetic = a ") of
            Right a -> a
            Left a -> error "Something"
    in res @?=  LabelInLabelType "Phonetic" ["a"] "="
    ]
```

works. The error message in the example above is obviously not optimal, but it is suitable for the sake of the current example.